# Select multiple values inside HTML tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I scraped a HTML page with multiple blocks of code like the following:

```
<div data-pnref="all" class="clearfix _5qo4">
<a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=671948073&
amp;extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22friends_tab%22%7D" ... />
```

I would like to retrieve the value of `data-hovercard`, and in particular the id in the URL: "671948073".

I tried both findAll and select in the BeautifulSoup module, but so far unsuccessfully.

Comment: yes, but I retrieve the entire block, and then I'm not able of extract the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `<div>` then find the `<a>`:

```
html = '<div data-pnref="all" class="clearfix _5qo4"><a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=671948073&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22friends_tab%22%7D"/></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

div = soup.find('div')
anchor = div.find('a')

data_hovercard = anchor['data-hovercard']

print data_hovercard
#/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=671948073&extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22friends_tab%22%7D
```

To get the value of the id, use `urlparse`:

```
import urlparse

parsed = urlparse.urlparse(data_hovercard)
parsed_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
hovercard_id = parsed_dict['id']

print hovercard_id
#['671948073']
```